# Specific format for a linear program

Tags: align, arrays

I am trying to format a linear programming problem in LaTeX. I want the objective function "max" and the constraints "s.c." to be left-aligned. However, I want a vertical line to the right of "s.c." that aligns with and separates the actual mathematical constraints. Here's a text representation of what I'm aiming for:

```
[P] max x1 -2x2 +x3
s.c.   | -2x1 +x2 +3x3 = 1
       | 2x1 +3x2 +4x3 ≤ 6
       | x1 +x2 +x3 ≥ 1
       | x1, x2, x3 ≥ 0
```

So idealy, the vertical line should be under max (either below the a or the end of the x of max).
Could someone guide me on how to achieve this in LaTeX?
Here is my attempt:

```
  \begin{align*} 
[\text{P}]: & \quad \text{max }  x_1 - 2x_2 + x_3 \\
\text{s.c.} & \begin{array}{|rl}
    & -2x_1 + x_2 + 3x_3 = 1 \\
    & 2x_1 + 3x_2 + 4x_3 \leq 6 \\
    & x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \geq 1 \\
    & x_1, x_2, x_3 \geq 0
\end{array}
\end{align*}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Also, the variables of the objective should be aligned with the variables of my constraints.

Comment: Ok I found the right patern thanks everyone for reading

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `t`op-anchored `alignedat` construction for the constraints, with some other box manipulation so the elements line up horizontally.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*} 
  [\text{P}]: \quad \text{max } & \hspace{.4pt}\phantom{-0}x_1 - 2x_2 + \phantom{0}x_3 \\
  \mathrlap{\text{s.c.}}\phantom{[\text{P}]: \quad \text{max }} & \hspace{-1.2em}\vrule\hspace{1.2em} 
  \begin{alignedat}[t]{3}
    -2x_1 & {}+{} &  x_2 & {}+{} & 3x_3 & = 1    \\
     2x_1 & {}+{} & 3x_2 & {}+{} & 4x_3 & \leq 6 \\
      x_1 & {}+{} &  x_2 & {}+{} &  x_3 & \geq 1 \\
      x_1\mathrlap{,} && x_2\mathrlap{,} && x_3 & \geq 0
  \end{alignedat}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```